# How to change shape of bottomTab

Tags: ios, macos, react-native, react-native-navigation, velo

I want to update react native navigation bottom tab bar shape in ios. As its set to default and i want to customise the bottom Tab to meet my desired result .Please help me so that i can solve this problem. Currently i am getting

current status

[image]

React native navigation is using uitabarcontroller in node modules.

and i want its shape is something like

Desired result

[image]

Please suggest me the approach for this.
Thanks

Comment: Below links might be useful to you https://github.com/jithinpala/JBTabBarAnimation and https://github.com/Abedalkareem/AMTabView

Comment: Check  [this](https://github.com/ndpniraj/custom-bottom-tab-navigation) out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library to achieve the desired result:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/vbrrollingpit

OR

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/amtabview

Comment: Thanks Bhavik for suggestion , but i want to achieve this UI in react-native. It would be great help if you could suggest me something on how to achieve this in React-native.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to design that in custom way and use svg for curved edges and smoothness